# Outputting a sorted list in order based on dictionaries value

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to output my sorted dictionary dictionary in ascending order based on my dictionaries values. These values are getting steamed in and are constantly changing. But I'm not getting the desired out put.

Right now I have this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, float> p in estimote_data.estimoteDictionary)
{
    Debug.Log("Key Valeu: " + p.Key + " Value value: " +  p.Value);         
}
```

This is placed in my update method and outputs the following:

> Key Valeu: 6491 Value value: 2.782559
>
> few lines of Unity Xcode debug stuff
>
> Key Valeu: 18087 Value value: 0.278256

I'm trying to get it so I can see the values auto sort themselves based on the Value value but I'm struggling to get this done. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SortedDictionary is sorted by Key. If you want to sort a list of items by some order, you need to tell the program:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, float> p in estimote_data.estimoteDictionary.OrderBy(p=>p.Value))
{
    Debug.Log("Key Valeu: " + p.Key + " Value value: " +  p.Value);         
}
```

This sorting will be expensive in the order of O(n log n). If you only used the Dictionary for the sorting, you could simply switch Key and Value, like this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<float, string> p in estimote_data.estimoteDictionary)
{
    Debug.Log("Key Valeu: " + p.Value+ " Value value: " +  p.Key);         
}
```